# How to print 5 random colors from an array of colors

Tags: java

I am trying to print 5 random colors (**colors can be repeated as long as they are random**) from an array of 10 colors that I created. I know I'm close-ish, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomColors
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
    Random r = new Random();

    String[] colors = {"red","green","blue","yellow","brown","black","white","indigo","orange","purple"};
    String[] solution = new String[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++)
    {
     solution[i] = colors[r.nextInt(10)];
     System.out.println(i);
    }

   }
}
```

I know my problem is that I'm trying to print "i", but I'm not sure what I should be combining to print.

Comment: I.ToString()???

Comment: Replace System.out.println(i); with System.out.println(solution[i]);

Comment: Thank you @apandey846, that was what I needed.

Comment: Note that even with the fixes suggested here, you're not going to get _different_ colours.

Comment: How can they be 5 different colours if they can be repeated? I'm not sure I understand the question...

Comment: What I meant to say is that they don't all have to be different, as long as they are chosen randomly. If it printed "Blue" 5 times, as long as that was the random result, it would be okay. I worded this question terribly, so my apologies to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Replace

> System.out.println(i);

with

> System.out.println(solution[i]);

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem that your algorithm might return the same color several times (`r.nextInt(10)` can return the same value multiple times).

A more straightforward solution could be to convert the array to a list, shuffle it (this is the "random" part), and print the first 5 elements:

```
List<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(colors);
Collections.shuffle(colorsList);
colorsList.stream().limit(5).forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Since the question was edited to say that non-unique colors are allowed, they can be printed like this:

```
IntStream.generate(() -> r.nextInt(colors.length))
    .limit(5)
    .mapToObj(i -> colors[i])
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This generates a stream of 5 random integers, and prints the elements by accessing the array.

Comment: It's okay if it returns the same color multiple times, as long as the results are random. I do see what you are saying though. Thank you.

Comment: Well, your question says "5 different random colors".

Comment: I realized that after you answered my question. I edited my post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply print `solution[i]` instead of `i`:

```
System.out.println(solution[i]);
```